# Order by key and delete first record of the query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following DB structure:

[image]

I need to delete the oldest token. How can I order by createdAt (oldest first) and delete only the first token of the resulted query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) method, and sort with [`limitToFirst`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToFirst) (or [`limitToLast`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToFirst) because of your negative timestamps) which will get the first created timestamp.

Not sure why your timestamps have a `-` in front of them. An example in Typescript could look something like the following;

```js
function searchAndDeleteTokens(userId: string): Promise<void> {
  return firebase.database().ref(`/users/${userId}/tokens`)
    .orderByChild('createdAt') 
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .once('value')
    .then(async snapshots => {
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        const tokenKey = snapshot.key;

        await deleteToken(userId, snapshot.key);

        return false;
      });
    });
}

async function deleteToken(userId: string, tokenId: string): Promise<void> {
  return firebase.database().ref(`/users/${userId}/tokens/${tokenId}`).delete();
}


searchAndDeleteTokens('133'); // User ID 133
```

Comment: Given that the `createdAt` values are all negative, I expect that OP is inverting those values (probably to allow reverse chronological sorting). In that case you'll want to use `limitToLast` to get the oldest item.